# Android studio does not allow to connect my application to internet

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, android-async-http, asynchttpclient

Hey I'm doing a web service login to my app, I've tried to connect to the internet, but it fails.

I've used httpurl connection and at the time of execute `openConnection()` and `getresponseCode()` it omits the code in that line.

I also tried with

`AsyncHttpclient` but it also fails.

I do not know what I'm doing wrong, I've tried with my webpage on xampp and also with www.google.com

the first one wait for more or less 3 seconds and then says it failed. The second one, fails from the first execution.

I tried to enter to the internet with chrome in android and it works!

Comment: Have you tried adding the required internet permission in the manifest.xml file?

Comment: AndroidStudio isn't preventing anything.  Its just a really fancy version of notepad.  It has no effect on the actions of your program or the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you added **INTERNET permission** on Manifest

Check if you are on a **PROXY configuration**

**If problem still persist, Try this**

Just create a WebServer class instance passing your context

```
WebServer server=new WebServer(getApplicationContext());
```

Now attach a listner to it

```
        server.setOnServerStatusListner(new WebServer.OnServerStatusListner() {
            @Override
            public void onServerResponded(String responce) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onServerRevoked() {

            }
        });
```

Now call the URL like Http GET reqest

```
server.connectWithGET("https://www.google.com/test.php?name=Eric");
```

Optionaly, If you are dealing with Http POST, Then create a DataRack

```
        List<DataRack> racks=new ArrayList<DataRack>();
        racks.add(new DataRack("name","Simon"));
        racks.add(new DataRack("age","40"));
        racks.add(new DataRack("location","Canada"));
```

And connect

```
server.connectWithPOST(MainActivity.this,"http://sangeethnandakumar.esy.es/PROJECTS/PUBLIC_SERVICE/posttest.php",racks);
```

**You need to include this library** : com.github.sangeethnandakumar:TestTube:v2.5.2

**Full documentations here** - https://github.com/sangeethnandakumar/TestTube